# Really Quick Question regarding First Order Differentiation - Linear?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$$(\cos^2 \theta \sin \theta)\frac{dy}{d\theta }+(\cos^3 \theta)y=1 \ \text{(with initial condition }y\left(\frac \pi 4\right)=0\text{).}$$

I'm asked to solve the equation above.

I managed to get $y = \frac{\tan x}{\sin x} + \frac{C}{\sin x}$

Now solving for $C$, with the initial condition, I would get $C = -1$.

However the answer is:

$$y = \sec(x) + \frac{1-\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 2}\csc(x)$$

I think I screwed up somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused. What is $x$? There is no $x$ in your original equation. Do you mean $\theta$?

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to $y'+\cot\theta y=\sec^2\theta\csc\theta$.  The standard method of first finding the homogeneous solution (which can be done with an integrating factor), and then finding a particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)y'(\theta)+\cos^3(\theta)y(\theta)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(\theta)+\cot(\theta)y(\theta)=\csc(\theta)\sec^2(\theta)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $r(\theta)=\exp\left[\int\cot(\theta)\space\text{d}\theta\right]=\sin(\theta)$.

Multiply both sides by $r(\theta)$:

---

$$\sin(\theta)y'(\theta)+\cos(\theta)y(\theta)=\sec^2(\theta)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Subsitute $\cos(\theta)=\frac{\text{d}\sin(\theta)}{\text{d}\theta}$:

---

$$\sin(\theta)y'(\theta)+\frac{\text{d}\sin(\theta)}{\text{d}\theta}\cdot y(\theta)=\sec^2(\theta)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Apply the reverse product rule:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\theta}\left(\sin(\theta)y(\theta)\right)=\sec^2(\theta)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\theta}\left(\sin(\theta)y(\theta)\right)\space\text{d}\theta=\int\sec^2(\theta)\space\text{d}\theta\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(\theta)y(\theta)=\tan(\theta)+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(\theta)=\csc(\theta)\left(\tan(\theta)+\text{C}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(\theta)=\text{C}\csc(\theta)+\sec(\theta)$$

---

So, with the intial condition $y\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=0$ we can find $\text{C}$:

$$0=\text{C}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$0=\text{C}\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{C}=-1$$

So, we get that:

$$y(\theta)=\sec(\theta)-\csc(\theta)$$

Comment: That's exactly what I did but that's not the right answer though. Look at the answer above?

Comment: You've $x$ in your answer and $\theta$ in the question?

Comment: And notice, that both the answer in your question and my answer fit to your ODE!

Comment: My bad it is meant to have theta as the answer. I got the same answer, so are you saying the the real answer given on top is wrong?

Comment: The one with (1-sqrt(2)/sqrt(2)*csc(theta)